# Error: exceeds block gas limit / transaction underpriced

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

When I call the function .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "5000000000" }); and attempt to deploy my contract, I get an :Error: exceeds block gas limit." When I switch to a much lower value such as 500000, I get a " transaction underpriced"

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

- It is not possible to submit a transaction with gas larger than the block gas limit. The gas field indicates the maximum gas you will pay, if it is too large the miner cannot include the transaction in a block and will drop it.
- Transaction underpriced indicates there's a pending transaction and you are sending a replacement. To replace a pending transaction the gasPrice has to have 10% increment.